# How to make cakephp add multiple records to a single table with a single HTTP POST?

Tags: php, cakephp

I would like to add multiple records to a single table in a single HTTP post. For single record, the HTTP post will look something like "http://127.0.0.1/app/model/api_add/data[Model][Field1]". How will the HTTP Post URL look like for adding multiple records? I am using cakephp 2.4.5

Below is the `add()` in the Controller:

```
public function add() 
{             
    if ($this->request->is('post')) 
    {
        $this->Model->create();
        $this->Model->saveAll($this->request->data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the cakebook:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Account.0.name', array('label' => 'Account name'));
echo $this->Form->input('Account.0.username');
echo $this->Form->input('Account.0.email');
```

So, you need to have iterator (in the example is 0, but you can loop like:

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    echo $this->Form->input('Account.'.$i.'.name', array('label' => 'Account name'));
    echo $this->Form->input('Account.'.$i.'.username');
    echo $this->Form->input('Account.'.$i.'.email');
}
```

[The article](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not need to use a form to submit the HTTP POST. I am using a HTTTP client to send the HTTP post directly. Hence, I would like to know how the HTTP POST URL will look like.

Comment: while you want POST, then the variables are not passed in the url. You can see how to pass this with curl here: http://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request,

You can also use browser plugin like: Postmain for chrome. at the end they will look like: data[Account][0][name]=value&data[Account][0][name]=value2 and so on